# how to create a wp7 tile with a transparent png as background and dynamic data on top of that

Tags: windows-phone-7

How do you create a wp7 tile with a png as background? What I have is a png that is white and transparent. I want the white to show on the tile, but I would also like to write some dynamic data on the transparent part, and how do you do that?

I have tried several different approaches like setting the opacity mask for different elements and write it out to a writeable bitmap but I can't get it to work properly.

The cowboy code below is what I have right now:

```
var backgroundUri = new Uri("Graphics/Icon_173.png", UriKind.Relative);
var imageStream = App.GetResourceStream(backgroundUri).Stream;
var bitmapImage = new BitmapImage();
bitmapImage.SetSource(imageStream);
ImageBrush backgroundBrush = new ImageBrush();
backgroundBrush.ImageSource = bitmapImage;
backgroundBrush.Opacity = 100;            

var backgroundRectangle = new Rectangle();
backgroundRectangle.Height = 173;
backgroundRectangle.Width = 173;
backgroundRectangle.Fill = Resources.Brushes.PhoneAccentBrush;
backgroundRectangle.OpacityMask = backgroundBrush;

WriteableBitmap writeableBitmap = new WriteableBitmap(173, 173);
writeableBitmap.Render(backgroundRectangle, new TranslateTransform());
```

this almost does what I want, I get the background from the background rectangle correct but the mask is black instead of white.

Comment: Have you tried using Colors.Transparent?

Comment: @willmel, on what should I set that color?

Comment: Either on backgroundRectangle.Fill = new SolidColorBrush(Colors.Transparent) or don't even do that code at all. At least for regular tiles, the OS handles the display of the accent color in the transparent spots of the image.

Comment: The transparent parts works just fine, the problem is that the white parts of the image turns white.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're probably not saving the image as a PNG. In your code you left out the save part, but if you use the `SaveJPEG` method, you'll obviously not get transparency.

Consider using the SavePNG method from the [WriteableBitmapEx](http://writeablebitmapex.codeplex.com) library, and see if that works better.

Or you could set the background like this:

```
backgroundBrush = (Brush)Application.Current.Resources["PhoneAccentBrush"];
```

Comment: Setting the background brush of what? As you see the rectangle has the background set.

Comment: Oh yeah, it should probably been the `Fill` property. I didn't notice your poor variable naming :p

Comment: +1 one on the poor variable naming :). I'm sort of in a experimental phase hence the poor naming. But I really want to figure this out, I'm going to test WriteableBitmapEx a try tomorrow otherwise the users (if I'll have any) have to settle with a less nice looking tile :(.

Comment: Using the WriteableBitmapEx plus the additional extension found here: http://writeablebitmapex.codeplex.com/discussions/274445 solved it.